# What is the "condition" property of ol.interaction.Modify used for in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have tried to use the "condition" property of ol.interaction.Modify to let users add/move vertex of a linestring only when the user press down "shift" key, like this:

```
this.modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: this.features,
        condition: function(event){
            return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&  ol.events.condition.singleClick(event)
        }
});
map.addInteraction(this.modifyInteraction);
```

However, when I test it, I can still add/move vertex of a linestring without pressing "shift". So my question is how can I allow user to add/move vertex only when the user press down "shift" key?

Thank you!

Comment: (just to make sure) Try `ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event)` ctrl key if you're not Mac.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!! Is there an explanation behind this?

Comment: I'm not sure but Shift key is to manually draw so it can be a conflict.

Comment: the asingment `return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&  ol.events.condition.singleClick(event)` is not correct. Just use `return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event)`